# Simple conditional to compare expiration and entry date failing to evaluate

Tags: conditionals, date-format

I'm trying to code more readable dates on posts which have been entered.

It will read "12 - 17 Jan" but if the month is across two months it will read "12 Jan - 2 Feb"

Spitting out my dates like so

```
<span>{entry_date format="%d %M"} -<br>{expiration_date format="%d %M"}</span>
```

Shows the dates are not evaluating to the same month... for instance the first entry is "21 JAN - 17 JUL"

If I run a conditional on this exact same entry...

```
{if {entry_date format="%M"}=={expiration_date format="%M"}}
SAME MONTH
{/if}
```

It's returning "SAME MONTH" am I overlooking something here? does the parse order mess with the conditional (I can't imagine it is in this instance) it may be worth mentioning that if I say "!=" does not equal... nothing is returned.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just around them by `'`

```
{if '{entry_date format="%M"}'=='{expiration_date format="%M"}'}
```

Regard's.

Comment: You absolute gem, I was using double quotations which kept breaking the statement. This worked a treat, thank you.

Comment: welcome, I am glad to see this help you.